# How to splice every "conditions" under 0th index particular key “logic” & value of a nested JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, loops

I have a nested object and I want to find the splice every "condition": 0th index key "logic" & value in it. Let's say object looks like this:

Original input:

```
[
  {
    "conditions": [
      {
        "logic": "AND",
        "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
        "condition": "Equals",
        "value": "122",
        "level": "first",
        "type": "condition"
      },
      {
        "level": "second",
        "type": "group",
        "nextChildLogic": "AND",
        "conditions": [
          {
            "logic": "AND",
            "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
            "condition": "Equals",
            "value": "123",
            "level": "second",
            "type": "condition"
          },
{
            "logic": "AND",
            "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
            "condition": "Equals",
            "value": "35645",
            "level": "second",
            "type": "condition"
          }
        ],
        "groupLogic": "AND"
      }
    ],
    "modeOfAuth": "otp"
  },
  {
    "conditions": [
      {
        "logic": "AND",
        "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
        "condition": "< Less than",
        "value": "12",
        "level": "first",
        "type": "condition"
      }
    ],
    "modeOfAuth": "frictionless"
  },
  {
    "conditions": [
      {
        "logic": "AND",
        "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
        "condition": "Equals",
        "value": "12",
        "level": "first",
        "type": "condition"
      },
      {
        "level": "second",
        "type": "group",
        "nextChildLogic": "AND",
        "conditions": [
          {
            "logic": "AND",
            "parameter": "Amount",
            "condition": "< Less than",
            "value": "12",
            "level": "second",
            "type": "condition"
          },
          {
            "logic": "AND",
            "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
            "condition": "Equals",
            "value": "345",
            "level": "second",
            "type": "condition"
          }

        ],
        "groupLogic": "AND"
      }
    ],
    "modeOfAuth": "frictionless"
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    "conditions": [
      {
        "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
        "condition": "Equals",
        "value": "122",
        "level": "first",
        "type": "condition"
      },
      {
        "level": "second",
        "type": "group",
        "nextChildLogic": "AND",
        "conditions": [
          {
            "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
            "condition": "Equals",
            "value": "123",
            "level": "second",
            "type": "condition"
          },
{
            "logic": "AND",
            "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
            "condition": "Equals",
            "value": "35645",
            "level": "second",
            "type": "condition"
          }
        ],
        "groupLogic": "AND"
      }
    ],
    "modeOfAuth": "otp"
  },
  {
    "conditions": [
      {
        "logic": "AND",
        "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
        "condition": "< Less than",
        "value": "12",
        "level": "first",
        "type": "condition"
      }
    ],
    "modeOfAuth": "frictionless"
  },
  {
    "conditions": [
      {
        "logic": "AND",
        "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
        "condition": "Equals",
        "value": "12",
        "level": "first",
        "type": "condition"
      },
      {
        "level": "second",
        "type": "group",
        "nextChildLogic": "AND",
        "conditions": [
          {
            "parameter": "Amount",
            "condition": "< Less than",
            "value": "12",
            "level": "second",
            "type": "condition"
          },
          {
            "logic": "AND",
            "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
            "condition": "Equals",
            "value": "345",
            "level": "second",
            "type": "condition"
          }

        ],
        "groupLogic": "AND"
      }
    ],
    "modeOfAuth": "frictionless"
  }
]
```

code:

```
const parseData = (data) => data.map(({conditions, ...rest}) => conditions.map(({logic, ...conditions}) => ({conditions, ...rest})));

console.log(parseData(data));
```

Tried above code. the above JSON object in all the indexes Every condition under only 0th index "logic" key need to be remove

Answer (score 1):

```
var recursive = b =>
  b.map((val, i) => {
    if (i === 0) delete val.logic;
    if (val.conditions) {
      val.conditions = recursive(val.conditions);
    }
    return val;
  });
```

Something like this should work, I'm simply deleting `logic` if it's the first element of array and also calling this function recursively for each nested `conditions` array inside these objects.